# ¿leo datos de un sensor de arduino con c# y los muestro en un label en form1 como puedo mostrar ese mismo dato en un form2?

Tags: c#, arduino

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Quiero mostrar ese dato en otro form logro mandar una vez pero no actualiza se queda con la primera lectura mientras en el form principal sigue cambiando la temperatura**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si se puede. Puedes guardarlo en una variable definida como pública y así podrás acceder a ella en cualquier Form.
por ejemplo, definir la variable fuera de tu ciclo:

```
static float m;
```

después ya agregas

```
   if (...)
    { 
      m= numero + "C";
      lablel1.Text = m;

    }
```

Comment: Sabes no funciona del método que me dijiste ya que al momento de pasar lo datos no guardaba nada en la varible y aparecía en 0 pero pude solucionarlo usando variables static con eso ya me reconoce el mismo dato y la temperatura en tiempo real en dos form pero me di una idea con tu comentario muchas gracias

Comment: Ya está modificado, por si a alguien más le sirve :D